# How do I set a textbox to multi-line in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, multiline

I have a report with many fields that I'm trying to get down to 1 page horizontally (I don't care whether it's 2 or 200 pages vertically... just don't want to have to deal with 2 pages wide by x pages long train-wreck).  That said, it deals with contact information.

My idea was to do:

```
Name:      Address:   City:      State:    ...
Jon Doe    Addr1      ThisTown    XX       ...    
           Addr2
           Addr3
-----------------------------------------------
Jane Doe   Addr1      ThisTown    XX       ...
           Addr2
           Addr3
-----------------------------------------------
```

Is there some way to set a `textbox` to be multi-line (or the SQL result)?  Have I missed something bloody obvious?

---

The CanGrow Property is on by default, and I've double checked that this is true.  My problem is that I don't know how to force a line-break. I get the 3 address fields that just fills a line, then wraps to another.  I've tried `/n`, `\n` (since I can never remember which is the correct slash to put), `<br>`, `<br />` (since the report will be viewed in a ReportViewer control in an ASP.NET website).  I can't think of any other ways to wrap the text.

Is there some way to get the results from the database as 3 lines of text/characters?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Alter the report's text box to:

```
= Fields!Addr1.Value + VbCrLf + 
  Fields!Addr2.Value + VbCrLf + 
  Fields!Addr3.Value
```

Comment: instead of using `VbCrLf` you may should use `System.Environment.NewLine` as best practices

Comment: @WiiMaxx And replace `+` to `&`

Answer (score 6):

I had an additional problem after putting in the `chr(10)` into the database.

In the field (within the report) add in:

```
=REPLACE(Fields!Addr1.Value, CHR(10), vbCrLf)
```

Answer (score 5):

My data was captured in a SL application, needed this for the field expression

```
=REPLACE(Fields!Text.Value, CHR(13), vbCrLf)
```

Comment: the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3582842/1993545) from Sam says already the same thing, so -1 for repeating

Comment: Used `System.Environment.NewLine` instead of `vbCrLf` as noted in another comment, other than that this worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 4):

Hitting Shift+Enter while typing in the textbox creates a line break.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to set the CanGrow property to **true** on the Textbox.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159116(SQL.90).aspx for some details.

Answer (score 1):

link break do this

chr(10)

Comment: Please provide your answer some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
= Fields!Field1.Value + System.Environment.NewLine + Fields!Field2.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

In RDLC reports, you can convert a textbox to placehoder.
Then right click that textbox placeholder, select placehoder properties and select HTML. Then for multiline to take effect, you have to insert `<br/>` tag between those lines.