# Multiline Parameters (textbox) in Sql Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, multiline

I am designing a report, the users enter some paramters for filter. But the parameter can be long and my textbox is so short and only one line as you see on the following picture

[image]

I want to make these textbox multiline but i dont know how to do that. I followed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567/how-do-i-set-a-textbox-to-multi-line-in-ssrs) but not worked for me

I use sql 2008 r2.

well I just want to make these textboxes multiline.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030808/ssrs-report-parameters-textarea-instead-of-textbox)

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer, but it did not work to me.. i think the problem is, the button is set as default. that means when i press enter, the button click event is triggered.. and the textbox is still one line